# How to test for effect modification and mediation by time-varying factors in a longitudinal context?

Tags: panel-data, causality, confounding, time-varying-covariate

I have longitudinal data with measures of an exposure, outcome, variables that may be mediators or effect modifiers, and confounders at 3 time points. I would like to account for time-invariant and time-varying confounding while testing for mediation and moderation of the exposure-outcome relationship. I have two questions:

1. What analytic method should I use to do this? I believe some form of g-methods is appropriate, perhaps g-estimation of structural nested marginal models? Any examples in the literature of studies addressing this would be helpful (testing both mediation and effect modification by time-varying factors).
2. How can I run these analyses practically in R? I came across the recent "gestools" package but that doesn't seem to allow effect modification by categorical variables, or mediation. Any examples of packages or code would be great.

Thank you!